# Find the surface area of S which is is the part of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ which lies in the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ay$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

How do I set up the integral to find the surface area if I only have the two shapes a sphere and a cylinder ?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=ay$ isn't a cylinder. For non-zero $a$, it's a cone.

Comment: @Frentos Well, $x^2+(y-a/2)^2=(a/2)^2$ looks like a cylinder.

Comment: Isn't that a similar question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893918/how-to-calculate-this-area-portion-of-a-sphere-inside-a-cylinder

Comment: @Nyfiken: quite right. I managed to take slices through $z$ *and* $y$ simultaneously and, not surprisingly, didn't end up with circles :-)