# Area of Sphere in Cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, surface-integrals

This was on my exam, and I didn't know how to solve it.

Problem: Find the area of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 4$ inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ above the $xy$-plane.

The way is tried to do it was that $dS=\sqrt{1+(dz/dx)^2 + (dz/dy)^2 } dA $

But when I tried to integrate I got a really messy integral.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change coordinates. Here's a link that helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894058/55622

Comment: Thank you so much. I did change coordinates, but I  parameterized x as cos(theta)+1 and y = sin(theta) instead of 0<= r<= cos(theta) which results in a nicer integral that is solvable.

Comment: Your original change of variables isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The surface integral is,

$$S = \int_{A} \sqrt{1+(z_x')^2+(z_y')^2}dA
=\int_{A} \frac2{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dA$$

Then, evaluate the integral in polar coordinates of the cylinder $r=2\cos\theta$,

$$S = 2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta\int_0^{2\cos\theta} \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}
=-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{4-r^2}|_0^{2\cos\theta}d\theta$$

$$ =8\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-\sin\theta)d\theta=4(\pi-2)$$